# How to load images from Images.xcassets into a UIImage with swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a images from the Images.xcassets folder and I want to load them into a UIImage programmatically using swift. The images are for a list so image 1 corresponds to list item 1.
How can I do this?
Please give me some code examples!

Answer (score 2):

```
let image = UIImage(named: "nameOfImageInXCAssets")
```

I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt on this one, but this is a very straight forward read the manual case.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

There's even a section called "Loading and Caching Images"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting errors when I try to load multiple images into UIImage. Is let and then else the correct strategy? Any Help?

Comment: let is not mutable, so once set, you can't change it. If you want to change the image, you should use var instead. var image = UIImage(named: "xyz")

Comment: Also to clarify, a UIImage is one image at a time, not multiple so I'm not quite clear on what you mean when you say "load multiple images into UIImage" - that's just something you can't do! You can however CHANGE the image - use var as I mentioned above.

Comment: I am trying to assign a specific image to a specific list item. Each list item has a different image. I need to do this for each item on the list. This is for UITableView.

Comment: I am having trouble getting the list item to link to the correct image.

Answer (score 2):

`let image = UIImage(named: "img_xxx")`